# Put selected rows from a GridView to a Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, listbox

I'm trying the folowing:

```
    List<object>selectedRows = new List<object>();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            selectedRows.Add(row);
        }

      for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
            selectedRowsList.Items.Add(selectedRows[i]);
        }
```

I have a button and GridView. Now I want the user to select rows manually and store them in a List, so that I can put them into a Listbox (the values with "" or ";" side by side). So take the row from GridView and display it as a row in my Listbox. Multiple rows should be one below the other like it's displayed in the GridView). How to do that? The code i've posted stores the values as "{index = ...}".

Comment: Example when user select 3 rows, selected 3 rows data have to display in listbox control? Am i correct?

Comment: Yes! So when I have four columns for example and the user selects three rows then each row should be displayed in a row in the Listbox. And the column elements side by side. Like it's in GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow  row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() +"  "+row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() +"  "+ row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        }
```

When we select rows using RowHeader, we get result as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Microsoft's ListBox displays the value of the DataGridViewRow object's ToString() method. Therefore you can fill the ListBox with string objects that are representation of every row in the DataGridView. So in the button's click event I modified your code as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> selectedRows = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            string currentRow = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                currentRow += String.Format("{0} ", cell.FormattedValue);
            }

            selectedRows.Add(currentRow);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(selectedRows[i]);
        }
    }
```